# Which is the suitable Memory for this OpenCL Kernel?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have been trying to do FFT in OpenCL. It worked for me with a Kernel like this,

```
     __kernel void butterfly(__global float2* twid, __global float2* X,
                    const int n,}
     {

        /* Butterfly structure*/
     }
```

I call this Kernel thousands of times. Thus READ/WRITE to a global memory is too much time taking. The twid(float2) array is just read, never manipulated and array X is READ & WRITE type of array.

1.Which is the most suitable type of memory for this?
2. If I use local memory, will I be able to pass it to another Kernel as an argument without copying it to global memory?

I am a beginner in OpenCL.

Answer (score 0):

Local memory is only usable within the work group; it can't be seen by other work groups and can't be used by other kernels. Only global memory and images and do those things.

Think of local memory as user-managed cache used to accelerate multiple access to the same global memory within a work group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing FFT for small bloks, you may fit into private memory. Otherwise, as Dithermaster said, use local memory.

Also, I've implemented some FFT kernels and strongly advice you to avoid usage of butterfly scheme unless you're 100% sure of it. Simple schemes (even matrix multiplication) may show better results because of vectorization & good memory access patterns. Butterfly scheme is optimized for sequential processing. On GPU it may show poor performance .

Comment: With an optimized butterfly, performance goes above even CUDAFFT! It runs magnitude faster than standard OpenCL-PyFFT!

Comment: Isn't private memory same as constant memory?